Description for APIRouter in FastAPI?
Suppose I have the following sample code:
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI

router_one = APIRouter(tags=["users"])
router_two = APIRouter(tags=["products"])

app = FastAPI(description="## Description for whole application")

@router_one.get("/users")
async def fn1():
    pass

@router_one.post("/users")
async def fn2():
    pass

@router_two.get("/products")
async def fn3():
    pass

@router_two.post("/products")
async def fn4():
    pass

app.include_router(router_one)
app.include_router(router_two)

It is rendered as below in swagger:

I know I can pass description argument for individual path operation functions but what I really need is to pass description argument to the APIRouter itself(I showed in the picture). I have some common information which is shared among the path operations below a certain tag like users.
I noticed that there is no api available for that in FastAPI like this:
router_one = APIRouter(tags=["users"], description=...)

# or

app.include_router(router_one, description=...)

Is there any other way to achieve that?

You can use the openapi_tags parameter of FastAPI class as below -
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI

router_one = APIRouter(tags=["users"])
router_two = APIRouter(tags=["products"])

app = FastAPI(
    description="## Description for whole application",
    openapi_tags=[
        {"name": "users", "description": "Operations with users"},
        {
            "name": "products",
            "description": "Operations with products",
            "externalDocs": {
                "description": "Items external docs",
                "url": "https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/",
            },
        },
    ],
)


@router_one.get("/users")
async def fn1():
    pass


@router_one.post("/users")
async def fn2():
    pass


@router_two.get("/products")
async def fn3():
    pass


@router_two.post("/products")
async def fn4():
    pass


app.include_router(router_one)
app.include_router(router_two)
Result

